# Android build error "Can't read shrinkedAndroid.jar"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

So I'm getting the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForHrmultipluscardPrerelease'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/posao/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.0.0/multidex/shrinkedAndroid.jar] (No such file or directory)

I've tried different devices, emulators, different versions of the SDK. 
I've also tried switching to the default gradle wrapper (It gives me the same error then)

Googling for shrinkedAndroid.jar doesn't give any benificial results

Comment: That means there is no any file exist.

Comment: Check that this file exits on the given path.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: The file does not exist in the directory at all. So it can't be gradle

Comment: This is caused by having multiDexEnabled set to true. Removing it will stop the error, but it will not be solving the problem. My application needs MultiDex to work at this point, and I can't get past the error Mislav is facing.

Comment: No it was my fault... One of my other project's exported jar file was compiled using Java 8 which was a big no from Android. Very cryptic error messages led me to hours down the wrong paths. Here is the link to my problem and the solution to what I did wrong. Thanks for replying.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703059/unable-to-fix-parseexception-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0034?noredirect=1#comment57152088_34703059

Answer (score 2):

You have `multiDexEnable:true`, try removing that.

Comment: It is not a solution for projects exceeding 64K in dex files. We have to use multiDexEnable:true

Comment: If you want multiDexEnable:true, then try  
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Answer (score 1):

In your app/build.gradle

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
}
```

Or use a later build tool version.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was that the Android SDK was corrupted somehow. Deleting the entire SDK and re-downloading and re-installing solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem as you,The reason maybe AndroidSDK corrupted somehow and delete the target file shrinkedAndroid.jar.

I just delete the target buildToolsVersion lib dir here:
~/Downloads/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2 
Then the AndroidStudio prompt me to 'Install Build Tools 23.0.2' when I sync Gradle.
Redownload it and I build the project success.