# How to create a jar usable in an Android-Studio Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, jar

*My Situation:*
I have created a Android-Studio Project with a sample Activity from Android-Studio.
I created a jar (not executable) with [following these steps](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_create_jar_files.htm) in eclipse(neon) with just one class and followed the [steps of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) to include that jar.
In the onCreate() method of my Activity I use the code in my jar by calling it's constructor.

*My Problem/Question:*
What is my Problem or where should I look? Do I create my jar in a wrong way or is there something in Android Studio I'm missing?

**Android Studio Message:**

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Android Studio Gradle Console** (with '--stacktrace' option but I've shortened the message a little):

```
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

...

20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
20:15:12.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
20:15:12.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
20:15:12.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
20:15:12.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
20:15:12.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
20:15:12.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:119)
20:15:12.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:349)
20:15:12.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:151)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:148)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:147)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 70 more
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1454)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:122)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1399)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:456)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:410)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
20:15:12.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: have u tried this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703059/unable-to-fix-parseexception-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.jar`File which you are trying to add to your `Android Project` is compiled with different `java compiler` which you are using in your `Android Project`.

There may be situation like that you are currently using `java v1.8` (**As per Your StackTrace**)

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java''
 finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

but the `jar` that you are using is compiled in any `lower version` of `java` (eg -**jdk1.7 or lower**). This problem came in eclipse is known as `major - minor version Exception`. Please replace your `older` jar with any `new` Jar.

---

What I did exactly to solve my problem:

> In **Android Studio** --> Module Settings --> Properties --> change 'Source Compatibility' and 'Target Compatibility' to Java 1.7
>
> and in my **Eclipse Project** --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Edit JRE System Library to 1.7 as well
>
> recompile the library and use that one in Android Studio then clean and rebuild the project in Android Studio.

Comment: I changed my build path in eclipse to JavaSE 1.8. And I still get the same errors when I use the jar.Both Android Studio and Eclipse use the same JDK 1.8.0_72

Comment: you are actually using `java1.8` earlier too. Please try to update your newly `third party jar` or use  lower version of `Java`  bcoz in java 1.8 and 1.7 is very different. 

Read this https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-major-differences-between-Java-7-and-8

Comment: Please re-compile all the codes after changing the `jdk version` then only try to test it on android.. Thanks..

Comment: great advice. Thanks.